# LED lights dimly lit when off

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

Here is a link to my home earthing condition when the lights are dimly lit  https://youtu.be/eqR-CawKdgw

Measuring a socket I am seeing 225 volts between hot and neutral as expected... But 91V from neutral to ground and 144V from hot to ground (when I would expect to see 225 volts).

My home is a 220 V single phase connection. All LED lights are glowing in my home.

Comment: https://youtu.be/eqR-CawKdgw

Comment: Are your switches dimmers, lighted switches, motion sensors, smart switches, anything like that?  Are you in the Philippines?

Comment: These are normal switches... Nothing fancy. No not in Philippines in India

Comment: Maybe the bulbs are glow in the dark? Only half kidding...I also saw https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134570/led-light-glowing-when-off?rq=1

Comment: Are the LED lights connected between switched hot and neutrai? Or between switched hot and earth?

Comment: They are connected between hot and neutral

Comment: And latest in progress... I took out the main fuses.. still the lights were glowing... I measured voltage between fuse outlets and earth, both hot and neutral showed 150V.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found that there was a leakage of current from the mains... The neutral was getting earthed from the streetlights and many of the houses are receiving current but due to lack of LED lighting they were unaware.